# Why does everyone keep saying "I'm so pooped" in the Splatoon 3 plaza?

Tags: splatoon-3

So, I recently got back into Splatoon after months of a hiatus, and come back to the plaza being plastered with "i'm so pooped."

What is this? Just an anomaly? A youtuber/streamer's inside joke? I don't keep up with Splat news all that much and I'm just so distraught that I don't know the meaning of this phrase and why everyone's saying it .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The genuine answer is somebody said they're pooped in a server most of us are in, then we all started saying it, then we started posting it to Twitter, then eventually Splatoon.
That's all there really is to it.

Comment: Who are "we" exactly?

Comment: I did see a twitter thread of people saying "I'm so farted" while digging around. I would like to know who "we" are though as well.

Comment: me and my friends:) we started the im so pooped thing

Comment: So your the one who's been making me question my mental state! Thank you for the clarity. I would not be able to live without it. Have a amazing day.

Comment: you're welcome!! u too:>

Comment: This is nice, but there's nothing proving your statement

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibile reasons, according to Reddit:

- finals just ended for a lot of universities, "I'm also pooped" means you are very tired
- it could be related to the meme that Frye often(?) gets bad Splatfest choices, and since another Splatfest was announced for december maybe Frye fans are complaining about it

[image]
<sub>with the courtesy of [FieryFetus](https://twitter.com/FieryFetus)</sub>

Comment: I can see these both being very valid. Finals for me were pretty mild compared to others so I don't share the sentiment but can definitely see it being the reason. I think the Frye not winning any Splatfests (at least not recently) is definitely the culprit though. Thanks for responding :)

Comment: Upon further investigation, it seems that the finals are the most probable, if not the cause. I'm going to go ahead and accept your answer.